# How to get first character of a string in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a SQL column with a length of 6. Now want to take only the first char of that column. Is there any string function in SQL to do this?

Answer (score 607, accepted):

`LEFT(colName, 1)` will also do this, also.  It's equivalent to `SUBSTRING(colName, 1, 1)`.

I like `LEFT`, since I find it a bit cleaner, but really, there's no difference either way.

Comment: I don't know about SQL server, but logically a database server may be able to optimise LEFT better than SUBSTRING when it is using an index.

Comment: @thomasrutter, Looking at an execution plan, SQL Server (at least 2008R2) internally translates `LEFT(colName, length)` into `SUBSTRING(colName, 1, length)`. So **there is no any optimizations** here, it's just a preference.

Comment: LEFT not works with Firebird 1.5

Answer (score 70):

I prefer:

```
SUBSTRING (my_column, 1, 1)
```

because it is Standard SQL-92 syntax and therefore more portable.

---

Strictly speaking, the standard version would be

```
SUBSTRING (my_column FROM 1 FOR 1)
```

The point is, transforming from one to the other, hence to any similar vendor variation, is trivial.

p.s. It was only recently pointed out to me that functions in standard SQL are  deliberately contrary, by having parameters lists that are not the conventional commalists, in order to make them easily identifiable as being from the standard!

Comment: Why does index start with 1 and not with 0? This returns the same result: SUBSTRING (my_column, 1, 1) = SUBSTRING (my_column, 0, 2). What is it in position 0?

Answer (score 21):

`SUBSTRING ( MyColumn, 1 , 1 )` for the first character and `SUBSTRING ( MyColumn, 1 , 2 )` for the first two.

Answer (score 17):

It is simple to achieve by the following

```
DECLARE @SomeString NVARCHAR(20) = 'This is some string'
DECLARE @Result NVARCHAR(20)
```

Either

```
SET @Result = SUBSTRING(@SomeString, 2, 3)
SELECT @Result
```

`@Result = his`

or

```
SET @Result = LEFT(@SomeString, 6)
SELECT @Result
```

`@Result = This i`

Answer (score 15):

```
SELECT SUBSTR(thatColumn, 1, 1) As NewColumn from student
```

Answer (score 5):

Select First two Character in selected Field with `Left(string,Number of Char in int)`

```
SELECT LEFT(FName, 2) AS FirstName FROM dbo.NameMaster
```

Answer (score 4):

If you search the first char of string in Sql string

```
SELECT CHARINDEX('char', 'my char')

=> return 4
```

Answer (score 3):

INPUT

```
STRMIDDLENAME
--------------
Aravind Chaterjee
Shivakumar
Robin Van Parsee

SELECT STRMIDDLENAME, 
CASE WHEN INSTR(STRMIDDLENAME,' ',1,2) != 0 THEN SUBSTR(STRMIDDLENAME,1,1) || SUBSTR(STRMIDDLENAME,INSTR(STRMIDDLENAME,' ',1,1)+1,1)||
SUBSTR(STRMIDDLENAME,INSTR(STRMIDDLENAME,' ',1,2)+1,1)
WHEN INSTR(STRMIDDLENAME,' ',1,1) != 0 THEN SUBSTR(STRMIDDLENAME,1,1) || SUBSTR(STRMIDDLENAME,INSTR(STRMIDDLENAME,' ',1,1)+1,1)
ELSE SUBSTR(STRMIDDLENAME,1,1)
END AS FIRSTLETTERS
FROM Dual;

OUTPUT
STRMIDDLENAME                    FIRSTLETTERS
---------                        -----------------
Aravind Chaterjee                AC           
Shivakumar                       S
Robin Van Parsee                 RVP
```