# Select from collection based on alphabetical range on a column

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

```
range = "e-h"
Term.all(:conditions => ["name[0] = ?", range.split("-")[0]..range.split("-")[1]])
```

This produces `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[0] = 'e','f','g','h')' at line 1: SELECT`terms`.* FROM`terms`WHERE (name[0] = 'e','f','g','h')`

How can I select from my Term table where the name column's first letter is between a range of letters?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example:

```
range = ('e'..'h')
Term.where("LEFT(name, 1) IN(?)", range.to_a)
```

For reference:

[('e'..'h')](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Range.html)
[LEFT(name, 1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/792294/how-to-get-first-character-of-a-string-in-sql)