# MySQL compare 2 digit year with today's date

Tags: sql, mysql

I have DOB stored in dB as 2 digit value (IE: 98,99,05...), how I can compare it to today's date to get age?

Tried different variations, even converted today's date to 2 digit but I cannot compare it...

```
TIMESTAMPDIFF(year, d.dob, DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%y')) AS age
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: ooh a y2k issue I haven't seen in 25 years..either fix your DOBs or make an assumption eg 05 dob is 2005 (but it may not be)  anyway a business rule needs to be decided upon.

Comment: Is this a preschool or senior citizens register? (You have to decide if 102 years old _or_ 2 years old makes most sense.)

Comment: Not senior citizens, just people from 1970+ till 2010.

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72607489/calculating-age-from-incomplete-sql-data

Comment: Just data I got, nothing much I can do,  I was thinking, that there is quick way just to compare and get the age.

Comment: just add 1900 to dob year where year >=70 and <=99 else add 2000 - I don't see the problem here.

Comment: Also you seem to be only storing year of birth - please add sample data as text.

Comment: without birth month and day, you cannot get age, even if you had 4 digit years.

Comment: [Lloyd's crashed in January 2020](https://www.theregister.com/2020/01/02/lloyds_outage/) due to such hacks. Before the COVID-19 lockdowns this was the big IT news

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did the work, but as somebody mentioned already, I cannot get exact age  without day and month of birth... just approximate age assuming everyone is born on 01.01....

```
TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, makedate(d.dob ,1), CURDATE()) AS age
```

Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like next query:

```
select
    year(current_date) - (yob + 1900),
    if(
        year(current_date) - (yob + 1900) > 100, 
        year(current_date) - (yob + 2000),
        year(current_date) - (yob + 1900)
    ) age
from t
```

just decide what the max age allowed.
[Play with query here](https://sqlize.online/sql/mysql80/d60adf7e58779d3c56f9b24ce1ea6430/)

Answer (score 0):

As you told that dob is ranges  from 1970 to 2010, and is stored as a DATE type column, you can compare it with today's date to calculate the age by adjusting the year component of each date. Here's how you can do it:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, 
                     CASE WHEN YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(dob, '%y')) > 10 THEN STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('19', dob), '%Y')
                          ELSE STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('20', dob), '%Y')
                     END,
                     CURDATE()) AS age
FROM your_table;
```

Comment: Sorry... forgot to mention, it is not stored as date... just integer, YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(dob, '%y')) is returning 'null' for me, also YEAR(STR_TO_DATE('95', '%y'))is 'null'.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the oldest supported birth year is 1970, you can approximate age best by assuming the person was born in the middle of the year and doing some simple math:

```
timestampdiff(year, case when d.dob >= 70 then '1900-07-01' else '2000-07-01' end + interval d.dob year, curdate())
```

But without birth month and day, you cannot calculate exact age.